# How can i put random values to css properties using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

I want to generate properties to a known number of divs but i can figure out where did i go wrong. What i have tried for now is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   for(var i=1; i<=7; i++)
   {
    var randBottom = Math.ceil(Math.random()*200); 
    var randHeight = Math.ceil(Math.random()*300)+200-randBottom;
    var randWidth = Math.ceil(Math.random()*50)+20;
    var oceanWidth= $("#ocean").css(["width"]);
    var randLeft= Math.ceil(Math.random()*oceanWidth)-randWidth;
     var cssObj = {
        'bottom' : randBottom+'px',
         'height' : randHeight+'px',
         'widht' : randWidth+'px
        };
    $("#bubble"+i).css(cssObj);
   }
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/dZJJu/) is a complete work-in-progress sample.

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/JdkPb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems with the code:

- Use the `width` method to get the size of the element, using `css(["width"])` doesn't give you the width as a number, it gives you an object with a property named `width` that is a string with the width and unit, e.g. `{ width: '420px' }`.
- You forgot to include the style for `left`.
- Specify `top` and `left` instead of `bottom` and `left`. (You may need to change the calculations for that.)
- You misspelled `'width'` as `'widht'`.
- You would probably want to subtract the width of the element before multiplying with the random number to calculate the left position, otherwise you get negative values.

This will at least place the elements somewhere:

```
for(var i=1; i<=7; i++)
   {
    var randBottom = Math.ceil(Math.random()*200); 
    var randHeight = Math.ceil(Math.random()*300)+200-randBottom;
    var randWidth = Math.ceil(Math.random()*50)+20;
    var oceanWidth= $("#ocean").width();
    var randLeft= Math.ceil(Math.random()*(oceanWidth-randWidth));
     var cssObj = {
        'left': randLeft + 'px',
        'top' : randBottom+'px',
         'height' : randHeight+'px',
         'width' : randWidth+'px'
        };
       console.log(cssObj);
    $("#bubble"+i).css(cssObj);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

There's some errors in your code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   for(var i=1; i<=7; i++)
   {
    var randBottom = Math.ceil(Math.random()*200); 
    var randHeight = Math.ceil(Math.random()*300)+200-randBottom;
    var randWidth = Math.ceil(Math.random()*50)+20;
    var oceanWidth= $("#ocean").css(["width"]);
    var randLeft= Math.ceil(Math.random()*oceanWidth)-randWidth;
     var cssObj = {
        'bottom' : randBottom+'px',
         'height' : randHeight+'px',
         'width' : randWidth+'px'
        };
    $("#bubble"+i).css(cssObj);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You forget ' at the end of last element in css object.

```
var cssObj = 
{
    'bottom' : randBottom + 'px',
    'height' : randHeight + 'px',
    'widht' : randWidth + 'px'
};
```